# How to use REMOVE or REPAIR feature in NSIS script?

Tags: nsis

I have used nsis script for creating installer.When i run my installer second time with same name,REPAIR and REMOVE should be check and do the corresponding operation.I have find out my application already installed or not using following codes,

```
Function checkinstall
   ReadRegStr $R0 HKLM "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\My app" "UninstallString" 
   IfFileExists $R0 +1 NotInstalled
   call nsDialogpage
   NotInstalled:
FunctionEnd

Function nsDialogpage
   nsDialogs::Create 1018
    Pop $Dialog
    ${If} $Dialog == error
        Abort
    ${EndIf}
    ${NSD_CreateRadioButton} 0 5u 100% 10u "Repair"
        Pop $hwnd
        ${NSD_AddStyle} $hwnd ${WS_GROUP}
        ${NSD_OnClick} $hwnd ???
    ${NSD_CreateRadioButton} 0 25u 100% 56u "Remove"
        Pop $hwnd
        ${NSD_OnClick} $hwnd ???
    nsDialogs::Show
```

If the user select repair button it should overwrites existing installation path else uninstall existing installed and continue with new one.what am i need do to replace the (???) of the above code

```
page custom checkinstall
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
```

My next page is Directory selection.so i need to call this page? How to achieve this?

1.How can i call un installer function if the user selects remove button?

```
   Function un.Init, section /o -un.Main UNSEC000,section -un.post UNSE001
```

these are the un installer funtions.How can i call these functions? i have tried call method but it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a callback function, like in the [nsDialogs documentation](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/nsDialogs/Readme.html), look for the `nsDialogsPageLeave` function in this example:

```
!include nsDialogs.nsh
!include LogicLib.nsh

Name nsDialogs
OutFile nsDialogs.exe

XPStyle on

Var Dialog
Var Label
Var Text

Page custom nsDialogsPage nsDialogsPageLeave
Page instfiles

Function nsDialogsPage

    nsDialogs::Create 1018
    Pop $Dialog

    ${If} $Dialog == error
        Abort
    ${EndIf}

    ${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 0 100% 12u "Hello, welcome to nsDialogs!"
    Pop $Label

    ${NSD_CreateText} 0 13u 100% -13u "Type something here..."
    Pop $Text
    ${NSD_OnChange} $Text nsDialogsPageTextChange

    nsDialogs::Show

FunctionEnd

Function nsDialogsPageLeave

    ${NSD_GetText} $Text $0
    MessageBox MB_OK "You typed:$\n$\n$0"

FunctionEnd

Function nsDialogsPageTextChange
    Pop $1 # $1 == $ Text
    ${NSD_GetText} $Text $0
    ${If} $0 == "hello"
        MessageBox MB_OK "right back at ya!"
    ${EndIf}
FunctionEnd

Section
    DetailPrint "hello world"
SectionEnd
```

Comment: thanks.but How can i call uninstaller function if the user choose remove button? because un.Init,section /o -un.Main UNSEC000 these are un installer funs.I have tried ${NSD_OnClick $hwnd un.Init.it returns error message only.I have edited my questions also.

Comment: I guess that you cannont call un.Init from installer, but if you create the unistaller with `WriteUninstaller unistaller.exe` you can call it with `ExecWait "$INSTDIR\uninstall.exe"`